# Subscribe method is not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular application which consists of a **form** and a **submit** button. When I fill the form and submit it, if the database injection operation was successful, I want it to return a success message and right after clean the form. To do that, I made us of the `subscribe` method, however, the code never goes inside this method and the desired functionalities are not triggered.

```
insertRecord(form : NgForm){
    this.service.postAsset(form.value).subscribe(res =>{
    this.toastr.success('Inserted succesfull', 'Asset Register');
    this.resetForm(form);
    });
  }
```

The `postAsset` method is working succesfully and the value is added to the database table, however `subscribe` method is never working. Whay may be causing this? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** As it requested, the `postAsset()` implementation;

```
postAsset(formData: Asset){
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/Create', formData);
  }
```

**Edit 2:** The error occurs a few seconds after submitting the form;

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:13804:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2781:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59285:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2780:60)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2553:47)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2856:34)
    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4102:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4139:21)
```

Comment: Please show the code for `postAsset()`

Comment: Add it to the question instead of the comments

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, I added.

Comment: Did you check your network console? Was the request successfully fired? Code 200?

Comment: Yes, is your API/service returning a success status code of any type for this operation?

Comment: @wentjun, Actually I directly checked the database itself, the values filled in the form successfully inserted into it. Also in console, any error occurred.

Comment: HttpClient responds to success or error status codes. Even if the database operation on the server side is successful, it needs to return at least a `200`. What is the error?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, particularly the parts about errors.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I noticed that after inserting an element, a few seconds later, an error occurs at the browser console. I am adding the error in the question, please check it.

Comment: Okay the issue is that HttpClient is trying to effectively do `JSON.parse()` on the response. What is the type of the response coming from the server? If it's not application/json, this error will occur. What exactly are you sending back from the server?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, the `Create()` function at the entity framework in ASP.NET application, returns `ViewResult` object.

Comment: You need to specify the information from your network tab, what type does the Response headers indicate? Try the following `return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/Create', formData, {responseType: 'text'})` and let us know if the error still occurs.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, it worked, thanks a lot! Please post an answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please trying adding option of `{responseType: 'text'}` to your HttpClient POST request:

```
postAsset(formData: Asset) {
  return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/Create', formData, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

This is mentioned in the HttpClient documentation under [Requesting non-JSON data](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data).

What seems to be happening with your request is that the server is returning something other than type `application/json`. HttpClient attempts by default to effectively do `JSON.parse()` behind the scenes unless you specify a different type. Trying to do `JSON.parse()` on a non-JSON string would cause the error you are experiencing.

I'd recommend to always return type of `application/json` if possible from your server to avoid needing to do this.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your code as below:

```js
postAsset(formData: Asset){
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/Create', formData)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any)
                return response;
            )
        );
  }
```

Add below line at top

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```